Problem with Docker bind mount: files from host not visible inside container
I’m using Play with Docker (PWD) to run Docker containers and am having an issue with mounting a directory from the host to the Docker container. Although the directory /home/test-mount on the host contains files, these files are not visible inside the container.
1. I created Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /container-directory
CMD ls -al && echo "File contents!" > container-file.txt && ls -al

2. I built the Docker image:
docker build -t my-image .

3. I run the container with the bind mount:
docker run -v /home/test-mount:/container-directory my-image


What I expected?
I expected to see the files from /home/test-mount on the host visible inside the container in the /container-directory directory.
Current Results:


"containter" looks like a typo

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  What if anything is in the host directory?

It should work. There is no problem in your dockerfile and command to run docker container with volume.
